# Combining Choice with Any fails to marshal without @XmlRootElement

Tags: jaxb

I'm using JAX-B to generate POJOs from a predefined XSD.
I encountered this element definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://order.example.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://order.example.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="Order">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3">
                        <xs:element name="Credit" type="CreditType" form="qualified"/>
                        <xs:element name="GiftCard" type="GiftCardType" form="qualified"/>
                    </xs:choice>
                    <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="CreditType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="GiftCardType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:long" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

As you notice there's an awful combination of a nested <choice/> with <any/>.

XJC generates this code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "creditOrGiftCardOrAny"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Order")
public class Order {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "GiftCard", namespace = "http://order.example.com", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "Credit", namespace = "http://order.example.com", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> creditOrGiftCardOrAny;
}
```

Where the property references JAXBElements instead of the generated classes of CreditType and GiftCardType.

If I try to marshal an Order object like this:

```
Order order = new Order();
CreditType credit = new CreditType();
credit.setNumber("4111111111111111");
order.getCreditOrGiftCardOrAny().add(credit);

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Order.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(order, System.out);
```

I get the following error:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.example.order.CreditType" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

Which can be solved by adding a binding that forces XJC to annotate the class, the problem is that in my case I have many occurrences of this issue and so having to add a binding for each type doesn't scale very well.

Anyone has a better suggestion?

I uploaded a maven project reproducing the issue: https://github.com/jcfandino/jaxb-choice
Just run:

```
git clone https://github.com/jcfandino/jaxb-choice.git && cd jaxb-choice
mvn test
```